# Jquery .append() not working with dynamically generated elements from a Wordpress plugin

Tags: jquery, forms, dynamic, append

First, I only know a bit of jQuery. I've searched through all the questions and answers about dynamically created content with jQuery, on this site, but have not been able to solve my issue.

I have appended some text on a form created by a WordPress search and filter  plugin that changes the page results every time the user clicks on a checkbox. I have been able to append the form on the initial page load using...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".sf-item-246").append('<br/><br/>Settings');
});
```

However, once the user click on one of the checkboxes, the form reverts back and loses the "append" script. I realize that I need to add something to my script to make it "stick," since the form is a dynamic element, but I can't figure what that might be.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean, the `.sf-item-246` gets changed every time?

Comment: What exactly is happening when you are clicking on the checbox? I mean which function is being called?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We need more details about this issue. Is there other code that could be affecting this? What functions are tied to other events?

Comment: The `.sf-item-246` is just the plugin's class for the particular `li` checkbox, that I decided to add my new heading, "Settings," after. It does not get changed every time. What happens exactly, is that after the page first loads, my heading appears just after list item `.sf-item-246`, exactly where it should, but as soon as I click on one of the checkboxes in the same list (doesn't matter which one), my heading disappears.

Comment: After further research, I realized that the WordPress Plugin that I'm using loads content via Ajax. Therefore I have now solved this issue. Thanks for listening. I need to close this question, but now sure how to do that.